# Connect two Smartphones without Internet (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, gps, connection

is it possible to create an App with Flutter, to create connection with two smartphones? And then to get the GPS coordinates and calculate the distance between smartphones, the maximum distance will be 100-200 meters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Wifi-Direct with a specific (your application specific) SSID.
Here's a link to a guide on how to do so in android
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct
You'll need to request the necessary permissions though
Bluetooth is another option for peer to peer communication on smartphones but I think that the range limitation might rule it out

Comment: This is clever thinking, but the range of wifi varies greatly among and between devices. In my home, for example, I barely get a usable signal from a desktop router that is less than 40 meters away.  I was unable to find specs for ANY smartphone - but there are apps to help determine the range.